# Why is datetime64 converted to timedelta64 when converting into a YYYY-MM string

Tags: pandas, numpy

I want to convert time columns (`dtype: datetime64[ns]`) in a `panda.DataFrame` into strings representing the year and month only.

It works as expected if all values in the column are valid.

```
0     2019-4
1    2017-12
dtype: object
```

But with missing values (`pandas.NaT`) in the column the result confuses me.

```
0   -1 days +23:59:59.999979806
1   -1 days +23:59:59.999798288
2                           NaT
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Or with `.unique()` it is `array([ -20194, -201712,   'NaT'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')`.

What happens here seems that somehow the result becomes a `timedelta64`. But I don't understand why this happens. The question is why does this happen?

The complete example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pyhton3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# series with missing values
series = pd.Series([
    np.datetime64('2019-04-08'),
    np.datetime64('2017-12-05')])

def year_month_string(cell):
    """Convert a datetime64 into string representation with
    year and month only.
    """
    if pd.isna(cell):
        return pd.NaT

    return '{}-{}'.format(cell.year, cell.month)

print(series.apply(year_month_string))
# 0     2019-4
# 1    2017-12
# dtype: object

# Series with a missing value
series_nat = pd.Series([
    np.datetime64('2019-04-08'),
    np.datetime64('2017-12-05'),
    pd.NaT])

result = series_nat.apply(year_month_string)
print(result)
# 0   -1 days +23:59:59.999979806
# 1   -1 days +23:59:59.999798288
# 2                           NaT
# dtype: timedelta64[ns]
print(result.unique())
# array([ -20194, -201712,   'NaT'], dtype='timedelta64[ns]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a custom function, use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with `%-m` (the minus strips the leading zeros):

```
series_nat.dt.strftime('%Y-%-m')
```

output:

```
0     2019-4
1    2017-12
2        NaN
dtype: object
```

`%m` would keep the leading zeros:

```
series_nat.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')
```

output:

```
0    2019-04
1    2017-12
2        NaN
dtype: object
```